# May have a memory leak in Java webapp - have question about garbage collection and session attributes

Tags: java, memory-leaks, reference, garbage-collection, session-variables

I've been profiling my webapp locally on my pc with VisualVM. I'm pretty certain that I have a small memory leak. After taking a snapshot of the application, I chose the object that had the most instantiated objects and looked through the **Allocation Call Tree** to see if I could find which class (of mine) was contributing to the 'potential leak'.

I found three of my classes in the tree, and took a look at the method's that were pinpointed.

Here is a snippet of code (a method) from one of my servlets - this method gets the names of session attributes that I want to keep in the session and removes the rest.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;


            try {           

            conn = ds.getConnection(); 
            stmt = conn.createStatement(); 

            HttpSession session = req.getSession();

            getExemptSessionAttributes(Customer_Number,rs,stmt,session);    

          }//try

            catch (Exception e) { }


            finally { 
                    if (rs != null) {
                      try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { ; }
                    }
                    if (stmt != null) {
                      try { stmt.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { ; }
                    }
                    if (conn != null) {
                      try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { ; }
                    }           

           }//finally        

       }//post            


    public void getExemptSessionAttributes(int Customer_Number, ResultSet rs, Statement stmt,                HttpSession session) {    
       try {
         rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select Name from exemptsessionattributes");
         String[] exemptAttributes = null;
         int count = 0;

         while(rs.next()) {
             count++;
          }
         rs.beforeFirst();

         exemptAttributes = new String[count];
         count = 0;

         while(rs.next()) {
            exemptAttributes[count] = rs.getString(1);
            count++;
            }
         session.setAttribute("ExemptSessionAttributes",exemptAttributes);

         //garbage collect
         exemptAttributes = null;
              }//try
              catch(Exception e) {}
    }//end

//....
```

The only modification I've made thus far, since profiling my webapp, was the addition of setting the **exemptAttributes[]** object array to null.

**My question is -** 
If a String array (or any object) is set into a session attribute, does that mean that the reference to that object, if not set to null in the code, is still 'referenced' and won't be garbage collected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a String array (or any object) is set into a session attribute, does that mean that the reference to that object, if not set to null in the code, is still 'referenced' and won't be garbage collected?

Not exactly.

If you have set an object as a session attribute, then that object will continue to be reachable (and not garbage collected) for as long as the `Session` object is reachable.  The `Session` object is most likely cached in memory by the servlet infrastructure for a long time.

In this case, assigning `null` to the local variable does nothing useful.  Firstly, the local is about to go out of scope anyway, and that has the same effect from a GC perspective.  Secondly, you've just copied the object reference into a data structure (the `Session` object) that has a longer lifetime than the local variable ... so the object will continue to be reachable anyway.

In short, the object continues to be reachable *irrespective* of whether (or not) you assign `null` to the local variable.

Possible way to combat this "leak" include:

- don't put a reference to the object into a session attribute,
- set the session attribute to `null`, or
- adjust the web container's session caching strategy so that idle sessions are dropped from the cache.
- implement a scheme to invalidation sessions (e.g. log users out) after a period of idleness.

Comment: With reference to your 4 suggestion (which I thank you for), I don't think I could avoid putting a reference to the object into a session attribute...option #2 - there's a good amount of session atts. that need to be available for the duration of the session... option #3 - that's interesting, can you tell me more about that? I wouldn't know how to do it...option #4 - I have <session-timeout> set to 20 mins in web.xml, does that suffice for invalidating the session?

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the exemptAttributes reference (not the actual object referenced by the reference) is the try block in your method. So the answer to your question seems to be a "**No**".

Could the leak be because you are not destroying the sessions? In other words, if you keep creating new sessions and setting exemptAttributes objects in these sessions, your memory usage **will** grow unless you are cleaning up old/unused sessions. (you can set a session timeout in web.xml)

Comment: I'm glad to know that. As I had originally thought, the scope of objects in a method are local and cease to exist thereafter, right? Regarding <session-timeout>, yes, its set to 20 mins in my web.xml.

Comment: The scope is actually the try {} block, not even the entire method.  The innermost pair of braces that contain the declaration define the scope.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your actual question, no, nulling that reference is doing close to nothing.  The variable is scoped only to that `try {}` block.  It goes out of scope as soon as you leave the try and no reference is being held by this class any longer.  There are very few 'real' cases where nulling a reference in a method does anything useful for garbage collection.  It's going to stick around until the session releases its reference regardless.

The strange way `ResultSet` and `Statement` are being used, or simply not cleaning up old sessions, seem like better candidates for a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your post. Could you please elaborate a little further as to what you mean about the ResultSet and Statement objects and how they're being used...and also about cleaning up old sessions?

Comment: What is the ResultSet that comes in as a method argument?  Where did it come from?  Why do you ignore it completely and overwrite the reference?  How is the Statement that's coming in being generated?  Who is closing it?  It just "looks weird" to take in a Statement that's in an unknown state as a method param and execute an arbitrary string SQL with it, then leave it dangling!

Comment: The ResultSet and Statement objects are created in the doPost method of the servlet. There is one Connection object created as well. Each object is closed in a finally block (contained in doPost method). The ResultSet object is initialized to null when it is created, and it gets passed in and used by the methods of the servlet when those methods are called. I can append these particular portions of code to my snippet so you can see for yourself.

Comment: It looks safe, but you do seem to misunderstand something about java.  Pointers are always passed by value in java.  Setting rs to something inside the method, does not cause the rs reference in your doPost to now point to something.  It remains null and will always be null.  They are separate references pointing to different things.  Closing the statement should still close it though.

Comment: Thank you for explaining things further. Mostly I use the ResultSet object and pass it into a method, which then runs a query, and after that, once the results are retrieved, the ResultSet object is no longer needed. Would it be more efficient to call the close() method on 'rs' inside the method?